# Remove UTC DateTime from a String using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a method to quickly strip out UTC DataTime values from a string of characters. The string could be long, and may not contain DateTime, but is likely:

```
string utctime = "1901-01-01T01:01:01.7730000";
```

Looking for Regex:

```
utctime  = Regex.Replace(utctime, @"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\+\d{4}", "");
```

But alas, its not working.

Comment: @gunr2171 - Apologies, just edited to try to improve question.

Comment: Your new pattern has a + in it, which doesn't appear in your sample input. Do you expect the input to have a plus in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 utctime = Regex.Replace(utctime, @"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d+)?(([+-]\d{2}:\d{2})|Z)?", "");
```

As one of the comments stated, your regex will not work for UTC and other formats. Try the above. It will match strings with or without offset, with or without fractional seconds, date only, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The right pointer and reading the Regex Expression tut helped me along!

Answer:

```
//                                : 2020 - 10 - 27  T  19 :  31 :  47 . 1670000 
utctime = Regex.Replace(utctime, @"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{7}", "");
```

Gotta use the right pattern!

EDIT adding Jon Skeet's explanation from the comments:

```
"1901-01-01T01:01:01.7730000Z" and 
"1901-01-01T01:01:01.7730000+00:00"
are both values indicating a date/time in UTC.
"1901-01-01T01:01:01.7730000" is just a local date/time, 
                              in an unspecified time zone.
```

I have used very little of regex in the past, but think I will start using more from now on!

Resource: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-regular-expressions/

Comment: Note that there's nothing in your input data or your "working" pattern that indicates this is a UTC value.

Comment: @JonSkeet - A little more info to explain might be helpful. I have no idea what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: @RustyNail As Jon mentioned, you'd need the uppercase T to indicate it is a UTC value. The format: yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss

Comment: @reakt: No, I didn't mention a T being missing because that's nothing to do with UTC. UTC isn't a *format* - it's related to the *time zone*. (The T makes it valid ISO-8601, which *is* a format, or at least a specification of a set of formats...)

Comment: "1901-01-01T01:01:01.7730000Z" and "1901-01-01T01:01:01.7730000+00:00" are both values indicating a date/time in UTC. "1901-01-01T01:01:01.7730000" is just a local date/time, in an unspecified time zone.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Excellent example! Editing to add your comment.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, that's a good distinction to make. However, UTC is not a time zone either - It is a time standard. Regarding formats, wouldn't you say that you need a format specifier "u" to designate UTC time standard without offset using "Z"?

Comment: @reakt: That's why I said "it's related to the time zone" rather than it *is* a time zone. I chose my words carefully. Although it's often used as "close enough to a time zone to be regarded as one" (in date/time APIs) whereas a format is very, very different. I really don't understand your question about format specifiers though... (Note that my comments have been entirely unrelated to C# so far, so if you're referring to the `DateTime` standard pattern 'u', I don't see how that's really relevant.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the clarification. I didn't see that you qualified it with "related to".  As for your question about format specifiers, I was referring to the DateTime.ToString method with overloads ToString(IFormatProvider) and ToString(String, IFormatProvider).

Comment: @reakt: Those don't have anything to do with whether "1901-01-01T01:01:01.7730000" can be said to be in UTC. However, this will be my last comment - Stack Overflow comment threads aren't designed for discussion.

Comment: @JonSkeet Perhaps pedantic semantics, but I concede Re: "format". Thanks!